# trouble with array duplicate filter android/java

Tags: java, android, arrays, algorithm

I have a string array witch could contain some duplicate values and I am trying to write a filter to eliminate any dups.

The code I pasted below works for all but the first element in the array and I cant figure out why.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

```
for(int i=0; i<forparts.length; i++){
        elem = forparts[i];
        for (int n=i+1; n<forparts.length; n++){
            elem2 = forparts[n];
            if (elem2.equalsIgnoreCase(elem)){
                forparts[n] = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do mean it does not work for the first element in the array?  What are you getting and what is your expected result?  As a side note: the answer by yock is an efficient way of removing duplicates in a list of Strings.

Comment: I mean that if the first element is duplicated somewhere in the array that second instance will not be removed as expected. I am not familiar with set. Ill give it a shot and see if i can manage to make it work that way. Thanks

Comment: I've checked the code. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking outside the box, must you use an array? The behavior you need is available from the Set interface in the Java Collections library.

```
Set<MyType> set = new LinkedHashSet<MyType>();
MyType obj = new MyType();
boolean bAdded;
bAdded = set.add(obj); // bAdded == true, set.size() == 1
bAdded = set.add(obj); //bAdded == false; set.size() == 1
```

This way you never need to filter dupes from your collection because they're never added in the first place.

Comment: I cheated and got it to work by adding an empty element to the beginning of the array. I just cant see why I needed to. Thanks for the help though. In the future I'll try to implement the set interface.